# Can we override default behaviour of swiper navigation arrows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am using [react swiper](https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper) to display multiple elements on screen in a loop. Is there a way I can override default behaviour of navigation arrows? I want to change the way navigation works at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Swiper API should have onSlideChange (not sure about the name) event. You can use this event and when this event happens check if this is the last slide and assign your action.